# Angular routing and controller not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes

New to Angular and cannot for the life of me figure out why routing is not working for me. It worked for a while, and then promptly stopped for some reason.

Additionally, it doesn't seem like my controller is working either, since when I copy the form HTML into the index.html file and try to upload a file, it doesn't seem to be running the uploadFile() function.

Here's my code:

**js/app.js**

```
angular.module('packager', ['ngRoute', 'MainCtrl', 'appRoutes', 'ngFileUpload'])
```

**js/appRoutes.js**

```
 angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: './views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .when('/package', {
        templateUrl: './views/package.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    });

}]);
```

**controllers/MainCtrl.js**

```
 angular.module('MainCtrl', []).controller('MainController', [$scope, $location, Upload, function($scope, $location, Upload) {
    $scope.upload = {};
    $scope.uploads = [];

    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        Upload.upload({
        url: '/upload'
        method: 'post'
        data: $scope.upload
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log($scope.upload)

        $scope.id = $scope.upload.id
        $scope.uploads.push(response.data);
        $scope.upload = {};

        $location.path('/package')
    }
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Packager</title>

    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="packager" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**views/home.html (one of two forms)**

```
<form ng-submit="uploadFile()">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" ngf-select required ng-model="upload.file"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: What is `Upload` in your controller? It doesn't appear to be defined. Also, where is the `ngFileUpload` module coming from? Don't see a `<script>` tag for that one

Comment: @Phil
I've updated the post, injecting Upload as per https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload, and added the script for ngFileUpload. Still no luck with the controller working, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. There were two syntax errors:

Forgot the commas in the upload object

```
Upload.upload({
    url: '/upload',
    method: 'post',
    data: $scope.upload
})
```

And forgot to put the injections in strings:

`"$scope", "$location", "Upload"`